# jQuery & Phonegap issues with preloading DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, mobile, cordova

I've been diving into google and stackoverflow before, but didn't find a solution for this.

My issue is the following:
I'm using PhoneGap (cordova 3.0) and jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 for android.

Before my first view loads I'm experiencing a white screen, which I guess is the DOM initializing before images are loaded on top.

I changed the background to black, but this one is still white.

What do I want to achieve?
When the view is not loaded completely, the background should be black that the user has the experience of "the app hasn't started yet".

**Update 1:**
All Javascript code now in onLoad and deviceready:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onLoad() {
           document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }
        function onDeviceReady() {
            ... code
        }
    <script>
</body>
```

Unfortunately no changes.

I found out that the amount of time the white screen is displayed is minimized after second app launch because of caching.

My Architecture is the following:
To overgo a timeout error I've got an index.html with the following structure in addition to an increased timeout value in the main file.

Main.java
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 10000);

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
            .ui-page { 
                -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     }
        </style>
        <script>
        window.location.href="./main.html";
    </script>   
    </head> 
<body>      
</body>
</html>
```

This is only for redirection to the actual file where images etc are loaded.
No Splash.

The white screen occurs after that, when loading the main.html which needs long time to load (multipage jQuery).
In the very first app start it's 1 second white screen.
after that it seems to be cached and takes <~100ms.

**Is it possible to pre-cache a webApp?**

Comment: Have you put your code in to a deviceready and/or dom is loaded listener?

Comment: I've put all of my javascript code now in deviceready. deviceready itself is called after onLoad() fired by the body tag. I've found out that the app starts very fast after opened once - it's cached. I'm not the only one with this white screen in the beginning. Even Pinterest and TED have it.

Comment: are you talking about a splash screen?

Comment: No, okay. I'll edit more Information

Comment: are you opening inappbrowser after the splash?

Comment: Phonegap/cordova runs in the inAppBrowser and there is no splash screen (or do you mean the white, unwanted flash)